# Using es6 map creates an objects it contains empty objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I searched a while but couldn't find the answer that I want. I am have a very simple question, how to get rid of the empty objects from Map.

```js
const friuts = [{
    apple: 'red',
    banana: 1
  },
  {
    apple: 'green',
    banana: 1
  },
  {
    apple: 'yellow',
    banana: 3
  }
]

const newObject = friuts.map(e =>
  ({ ...e.banana === 1 ? {
      apple: e.apple
    } :
      []
  })
)


console.log(newObject)
```

If you check the console.log it contains an empty object at the end

```
[
  {
    "apple": "red"
  },
  {
    "apple": "green"
  },
  {} <--- empty 
]
```

Also I tried `undefined` or below code, but just can't get rid of the empty objects.

```
...e.banana === 1 &&
    {
        apple: e.apple
    }
```

I understand this can be easily done by using other methods like `filter`. However, I am learning `Map`, so I'd like to learn how to get rid of the empty objects from map.

Sorry for if the question has been asked before. I will remove the question if it is duplicated.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. And even if someone post a cryptic answer with a crazy way for skipping elements using `map` only, it will make little sense, since the code should be readable. For each task you need to use the correct tool, and the tool here is `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with `map`, which returns one result element per input element.

You can either add a `filter` to the chain or use `flatMap` instead:

```js
const fruits = [
  {
    apple: 'red',
    banana: 1
  },
  {
    apple: 'green',
    banana: 1
  },
  {
    apple: 'yellow',
    banana: 3
  },
]

console.log(fruits.filter(e =>
  e.banana === 1
).map(e =>
  ({
    apple: e.apple
  })
));

console.log(fruits.flatMap(e =>
  e.banana === 1
    ? [{
      apple: e.apple
    }]
    : []
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newObject = friuts.map(e => {
return e.banana === 1 ? { apple: e.apple } : {}
}).filter(e => Object.keys(e).length > 0)


console.log(newObject)
```

Why not do this instead? It don't see a point of using spread operator here